# Does a Patronus take form of an animal only?

Tags: harry-potter

So far what I can remember from books, I have encountered Patronus of a form belonging to Animal Kingdom only. Here's the list:

- Harry Potter / James Potter: Stag
- Hermione Granger: Otter
- Ron Weasley: Jack Russell Terrier
- Albus Dumbledore: Phoenix
- Lily Potter / Snape: Doe
- Ginny Weasley: Horse
- Luna Lovegood: Hare
- Nymphadora Tonks: Jack Rabbit
- Remus Lupin / Nymphadora Tonks: Wolf
- Minerva McGonagall / Dolores Umbridge: Cat
- Kingsley Shacklebolt: Lynx
- Arthur Weasley: Weasle
- Cho Chang: Swan
- Seamus Finnigan: Fox
- Ernie Macmillan: Boar
- Aberforth Dumbledore: Goat

I know that a Patronus is unique to a person and it can change because of emotional upheaval.

But, what exactly is the rule of creating Patronus form? Can I create a Patronus of a form X-wings or R2-D2 or Millennium Falcon or USS Enterprise-E or TARDIS?

Comment: Well I supposed if you were to identify as an attack helicopter your Patronus might look like one of those...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Rowling, corporeal Patronus' are animals. If you want to be pedantic, you can argue that incorporeal Patronus' are non-animal Patronus'. But as JKR says, if it's a true Patronus, it's an animal.

> The Patronus is the most famous (and famously difficult) defensive charm. The aim is to produce a silvery-white guardian or protector, **which takes the form of an animal.**
>
> *[...]*
>
> The incorporeal Patronus is not a true Patronus and while it will give limited protection, it cannot provide the defensive power of the corporeal Patronus, **which has the form and substance of an animal.**
>   <sub>[Patronus Charm by J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm)</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>